# jQuery: Button will not submit after .removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to perform some basic form validation in Wordpress, this is more or less my first attempt at JS/jQuery.

I have the following script which prevents a button from submitting a form if the `_sku` value empty. This works, however after the function has fired, and the user enters a value in '_sku' the button is still disabled. What is the best method here of re-setting the button to be active.

```
(function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
            if ($("#_sku").val() == '') {
                alert("Please enter a valid GTIN");
                $('#ajax-loading').hide();
                $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled'); 
            }
            return false;
        });
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Its because you're preventing the form from being submitted (using `return false`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: move the `return false` to *inside* the if statement

```
      jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
        if ($("#_sku").val() == '') {
            alert("Please enter a valid GTIN");
            $('#ajax-loading').hide();
            $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled'); 
            return false; // move this inside the if statement
        }
    });
```

This is because if the `return false;` is *outside* of the if statement, it will return false even if `_sku` has a value

Comment: This even won't work because OP wants to submit the form after removing class meaning you need to explicitly submit the form (on click of #publish).

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand what the OP wants... @BhojendraNepal

Answer (score 1):

You're always going to exit the function when it reaches the `return false` line.
Try:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
         jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
            if ($("#_sku").val() == '') {
                alert("Please enter a valid GTIN");
                $('#ajax-loading').hide();
                $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                return false; 
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code you always return `false` whatever the result of validation of field `_sku`

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit code in php file then once the form is submitted. Then simply display value with disabled "_sku" like you are doing right now. But name of input type should be something else. And save the value in hidden value with name as _sku. This will not ask for _sku again.

Answer (score 0):

```
this may help you,

(function($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
         jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
            if ($("#_sku").val() == '') {
                alert("Please enter a valid GTIN");
                $('#ajax-loading').hide();
                $('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled'); 
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#ajax-loading').hide();
                $('#publish').addClass('button-primary-disabled'); 
                return true;
            }

        });
    });
    enter code here

}(jQuery));
```